# Explain recursive functions in Free Code Camp's JavaScript guide

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to programming and learning from #freecodecamp

This question arises from the JavaScript basic course--- what happens in

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]
  }
}
```

```
console.log(sum([2, 4, 6, 8], 2)) // Shows 6 in console
```

Where do the numbers come from? And how are they add to each other if the first run is `sum([2, 4, 6, 8], 1) + 4` and second is `sum([2, 4, 6, 8], 0) + 2 + 4`?

Comment: "Play computer" with a pencil and paper: write down each step that's happening, the values at each step, and track the flow. Alternatively step through it with the debugger, but I'm not sure that's any clearer.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-recursion-in-javascript/ may help?

Comment: ...and the last part is `0 + 2 + 4` because `sum([2, 4, 6, 8], 0)` returns `0` .

Comment: Tangential: If I **did** use recursion for this (reducing over the slice seems cleaner) I probably would have recursed over the slice instead of the counter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Watch the process, step by step, like this

```js
function sumOfFirstNValues(arr, n) {
  console.log(`Asked to calculate the sum of the first ${n} values of ${arr}, i.e. of [${arr.slice(0,n)}].`)

  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    console.log(`Breaking this down into the first ${n-1} items and the single value ${arr[n-1]}.`)
    return sumOfFirstNValues(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]
  }
}

console.log(sumOfFirstNValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3))
```